# LibreOffice Base subform displays unrelated records

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, pervasive, openoffice-base, libreoffice-base

I would like help solving a problem with a LibreOffice Base subform. I think the subform should be displaying only the records that are related to the record displayed in the parent form. But the subform is actually displaying every record in its data source, regardless of the relationship to the record in the parent form.

The parent form displays a manufacturing work order. It draws data from a query `Work Ticket Traveler` which consists of fields:

```
WorkTktRecordNo
Number
Date
ItemID
ItemDescription
DisplayQty
DisplayUOM
```

The subform displays materials needed. It draws data from a subquery `WTT Subform` which consists of fields:

```
WorkTktRecordNo
ComponentNo
ComponentRecordNo
QtyRequired
```

You can readily see that the link field is `WorkTktRecordNo`. In the subform properties, the link master field is `WorkTktRecordNo` and the link slave field is `WorkTktRecordNo`. So this should cause the subform to display records from the subquery which are related through `WorkTktRecordNo`.

The only control in the subform is a table control which displays the four fields. This table control is the one with the problem: it displays every record in the subquery.

- client: LibreOffice 4.1.5.3 (Windows 7 Pro SP1)
- server: Pervasive PSQL v10 SP2 Workgroup (10.12.16.0), via ODBC (Windows XP SP3)

Answer (score 0):

Did you typed these field names or you selected them using the buttons? Selecting from the drop down boxes will paste the appropriate field name.